# SSIS package works in debug mode, but hangs at step 2 when launched from the SQL Server job

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019

Have a bit of a strange question here.

We had a job in SQL Server that was being suspended on step 2 of an SSIS package. However whern I run the SSIS package in DEBUG mode it works fine.  However if I launch the job from SQL Server it hangs at step 2.

Step 2 basically returns about 2 million rows changes null to a value joins against another table  and creates an update table.

It is strange that bit works in debug mode but stalls when launched from SQL server...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Stalls" Is the query blocked by another query when running from SQL Server?

Comment: Hi Lukasz, As far as we can see there is no other querys.  Works fine if we launch from debug in SSIS.  Fails at step2 if we launch from SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the number of jobs running on the sql server. Attached a few more processors to the server and it works fine now